# Hour difference when inserting default TIMESTAMP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp, timezone

I'm working with a MySQL database where I have a table named 'venta' with a 'create_at' field of TIMESTAMP type that by default takes the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value.

When I insert data into the table, I notice that 'create_at' saves the current time value but with a 4-hour lead. I've tried changing the timezone of both the database server and the application, but this lead still persists.

I've tried setting the timezone through the following query:
`SET @@global.time_zone = 'Pacific SA Standard Time';` 
And I also tried adjusting the time at the moment of insertion, using the CONVERT_TZ() function, but it still has the 4-hour lead.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how can I fix it so the TIMESTAMP reflects the exact current time when an insertion is made?

Thank you in advance for your help."

Comment: Use not TIMESTAMP but DATETIME.

Comment: TIMESTAMP is very problematic.  internally it effectively stores a UTC time, but whenever you read or write it, it is converted from/to the timezone of the current database session.  you are much better off using a DATETIME type, and explicitly always using UTC (so using and defaulting it UTC_TIMESTAMP(), not CURRENT_TIMESTAMP/NOW()).

Comment: You need specific privileges to set the global time zone in a query ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)), but it feels pointless to make global changes that won't survive a restart. Did you mean to change the per-session value?

Answer (score 0):

Set the server timezone:
If the server timezone is not what you expect, you can set it globally by modifying the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf or my.ini) and adding the following line under the [mysqld] section:

```
default_time_zone = 'Pacific SA Standard Time';
```

Or you can execute the following query at the beginning of your session:

```
SET time_zone = 'Pacific SA Standard Time';
```